# Avoid unnecessary include statements in SQL database query for ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

There are some times where I have a user and would like to check whether they are in the organization that owns the item they are trying to access. Let's say the tables in my SQL server look like this:

- Table: Organization
- Table: User

  - Column: OrganizationID (foreign key to Organization table)
- Table: Item

  - Column: OrganizationID (foreign key to Organization table)

Edit: however, my models do not have OrganizationID directly but rather the organization, as below:

```cs
public class Item{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemSomeProperty { get; set; }
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set;}
}
```

And similar as above for User.

So anyways, in my Controller right now I am doing something to the effect of:

```cs
user = await _context.User.Include(c => c.Organization).Where(c => c.UserID == thisUserID).FirstOrDefaultAsync();


itemList = await _context.Items
    .Include(c => c.Organization)
    .Select(Some stuff)
    .Where(c => c.Organization == user.Organization)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Is there a way to avoid these unnecessary includes and just compare the actual IDs? I don't need any other info about the organization so I don't want an extra Include. I would also like to avoid doing extra migrations to add something like "public int OrganizationID" to each model; plus I'd need to awkwardly change the name of that so that it doesn't conflict with the existing FK in the table (which is also called OrganizationID).

In my mind, the ID is already present when I look at the tables with SQL Server Management Studio, since that's literally what the foreign key is - I just need to grab the value of the foreign key instead of having it assume I want the entire Organization object. But I am not a SQL expert.

Edited for clarity and a bit more detail on what the models look like.

Comment: You can replace your Organization properly with the FK_ID column directly like public int OrganizationID{ get; set; }, In this, it will not bring the object. If you have both, comment the Organization property(public virtual Organization? organization{ get; set; } Works for me

Comment: Includes are unnecessary if you use `Select`.  Safely remove them.

Comment: Or as a single sub-query; `.Where(c => c.Organization.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == thisUserID))` which would also work if this was a many-many join.

Comment: I keep forgetting about Select. That can just grab the foreign key itself and not the full object?

Answer (score 0):

In your model design, `User` and `Item` all have a property `OrganizationID`, So if you don't want to use `include(xxx)`, You can use `OrganizationID` as a query condition.

```
//select User's fk

var userfk = _context.User
.Where(c => c.UserID == thisUserID)
.Select(c => c.OrganizationID)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

//if item and user has the same fk,so they are in the same Organization

List<string> itemList = _context.Items
.Where(c => c.OrganizationID == userfk)
.Select(c => c.ItemName)
.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: At the moment in my model design, the User and Item do not have OrganizationID. They only have "public virtual Organization Organization". My point was that when I look at the SQL Server Explorer, I see the foreign key OrganizationID. I wanted to just use that directly instead of having to include the organization, since what I care about is still the OrganizationID

Comment: Include the OrganizationId property in your model and reference it in the EF relationship definition. The attribute is required in the database. If you don't include it in your model, EF creates it as a 'Shadow Foreign Key', meaning it's there but you can't use it directly. If you include it in the model you can use it in your query criterion as suggested above.

Comment: Hi@S. B. , As @pjs said, If there is no foreign key specified in your entity class, The database will create a `shadow foreign key property` in your database, But you can't use it directly. i think Use foreign keys as query conditions is the simplest SQL statement if you don't want to use `include()` in your sql. Refer to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) can help you learn more about `shadow foreign key property`.